# SQL Weekly Data Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

We have a database which is updated every Sunday the dataset looks like below;

[AccountID] [AccountName] [AccountContact] [Package] [NextTransactionDate] [ReportDate]

I use this data to create a power BI query which is automated to run every Monday as the data is updated every Sunday afternoon

I only want to use the data that has come in on the latest Sunday and not the data from the previous weeks. i.e. [ReportDate]
The BI report only needs to show the data from let's say 25/10/20 and then on the next cycle 01/11/20 and so on. But this has to be automated using a query so it doesn't need to manually update every week

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server (ssms)?

Comment: I am using MS SQL (SSMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a `where` statement base on current db time in your query

```
WHERE ReportDate >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
```

this should work just fine.

Comment: Done.. Sorry I am new :D